# Golang - Help gnosis transaction hash not calculated right

Tags: go-ethereum, golang, gnosis-safe, gnosis

I have been trying to submit a transaction to gnosis rinkeby api but always the server response is that the hash is not correct and suggest's the lazy way which is not safe for what I want to do so I can not use the lazy approach. Can somebody tell me what am I missing from the protocol? Thanks

[Here is the code on Github](https://github.com/revision-team/gnosis-tx/blob/master/main.go)

```go
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "math/big"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "strings"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common/hexutil"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common/math"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/signer/core"
)

const ZERO_ADDR = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

type safeNonceResponse struct {
    Address         string   `json:"address"`
    Nonce           int64    `json:"nonce"`
    Threshold       int64    `json:"threshold"`
    Owners          []string `json:"owners"`
    MasterCopy      string   `json:"masterCopy"`
    Modules         []string `json:"modules"`
    FallbackHandler string   `json:"fallbackHandler"`
    Guard           string   `json:"guard"`
    Version         string   `json:"version"`
}

func getSafeNonce(safe string) (*int64, error) {
    resp, err := http.Get("https://safe-transaction.rinkeby.gnosis.io/api/v1/safes/" + safe)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var data safeNonceResponse
    if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &data); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &data.Nonce, nil
}

type gasEstimationRequest struct {
    To        string  `json:"to"`
    Value     int64   `json:"value"`
    Data      *string `json:"data"`
    Operation int     `json:"operation"`
    GasToken  *string `json:"gasToken"`
}

type gasEstimationResponse struct {
    SafeTxGas      string `json:"safeTxGas"`
    BaseGas        string `json:"baseGas"`
    DataGas        string `json:"dataGas"`
    OperationalGas string `json:"operationalGas"`
    GasPrice       string `json:"gasPrice"`
    LastUsedNonce  int64  `json:"lastUsedNonce"`
    GasToken       string `json:"gasToken"`
    RefundReceiver string `json:"refundReceiver"`
}

func getGasEstimation(to, safe string, value int64) (*int64, error) {
    request := gasEstimationRequest{
        To:        to,
        Value:     value,
        Data:      nil,
        Operation: 0,
        GasToken:  nil,
    }

    req, err := json.Marshal(request)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    resp, err := http.Post("https://safe-relay.rinkeby.gnosis.io/api/v2/safes/"+safe+"/transactions/estimate/", "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(req))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var data gasEstimationResponse
    if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &data); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    safeTxGas, err := strconv.ParseInt(data.SafeTxGas, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &safeTxGas, nil
}

type gnosisTxRequest struct {
    To                      string  `json:"to"`
    Value                   int64   `json:"value"`
    Data                    *string `json:"data"`
    Operation               int64   `json:"operation"`
    GasToken                string  `json:"gasToken"`
    SafeTxGas               int64   `json:"safeTxGas"`
    BaseGas                 int64   `json:"baseGas"`
    GasPrice                int64   `json:"gasPrice"`
    RefundReceiver          string  `json:"refundReceiver"`
    Nonce                   int64   `json:"nonce"`
    ContractTransactionHash string  `json:"contractTransactionHash"`
    Sender                  string  `json:"sender"`
    Signature               string  `json:"signature"`
    Origin                  *string `json:"origin"`
}

type gnosisTxErrResponse struct {
    NonFieldErrors []string `json:"nonFieldErrors"`
}

func sendGnosisTx(from, to, safe string, amount, safeTxGas, nonce int64, hash, signature string) error {
    request := gnosisTxRequest{
        To:                      to,
        Value:                   amount,
        Data:                    nil,
        Operation:               0,
        GasToken:                ZERO_ADDR,
        SafeTxGas:               safeTxGas,
        BaseGas:                 0,
        GasPrice:                0,
        RefundReceiver:          ZERO_ADDR,
        Nonce:                   nonce,
        ContractTransactionHash: hash,
        Sender:                  from,
        Signature:               signature,
        Origin:                  nil,
    }

    req, err := json.Marshal(request)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    resp, err := http.Post("https://safe-transaction.rinkeby.gnosis.io/api/v1/safes/"+safe+"/multisig-transactions/", "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(req))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if resp.StatusCode == http.StatusOK {
        return nil
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var data gnosisTxErrResponse
    if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &data); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return errors.New(strings.Join(data.NonFieldErrors, "\n"))
}

func sendTransaction(from, to, safe string, amount int64, privKey string) error {
    // get current safe nonce
    nonce, err := getSafeNonce(safe)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    fmt.Println("nonce:", *nonce)

    // get gas estimation
    safeTxGas, err := getGasEstimation(to, safe, amount)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    fmt.Println("safeTxGas:", safeTxGas)

    // get contract transaction hash
    gnosisSafeTx := core.GnosisSafeTx{
        Sender:         common.NewMixedcaseAddress(common.HexToAddress(from)),
        Safe:           common.NewMixedcaseAddress(common.HexToAddress(safe)),
        To:             common.NewMixedcaseAddress(common.HexToAddress(to)),
        Value:          *math.NewDecimal256(amount),
        GasPrice:       *math.NewDecimal256(0),
        Data:           &hexutil.Bytes{},
        Operation:      0,
        GasToken:       common.HexToAddress(ZERO_ADDR),
        RefundReceiver: common.HexToAddress(ZERO_ADDR),
        BaseGas:        *common.Big0,
        SafeTxGas:      *big.NewInt(*safeTxGas),
        Nonce:          *big.NewInt(*nonce),
    }

    typedData := gnosisSafeTx.ToTypedData()

    domainHash, err := typedData.HashStruct("EIP712Domain", typedData.Domain.Map())
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    primaryTypeHash, err := typedData.HashStruct(typedData.PrimaryType, typedData.Message)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    encodedTx := []byte{1, 25}
    encodedTx = append(encodedTx, domainHash...)
    encodedTx = append(encodedTx, primaryTypeHash...)

    encodedTxHash := crypto.Keccak256Hash(encodedTx)

    fmt.Println("encodedTxHash:", encodedTxHash.Hex())

    // sign
    privateKey, err := crypto.HexToECDSA(privKey)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    signature, err := crypto.Sign(encodedTxHash.Bytes(), privateKey)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if signature[64] == 0 || signature[64] == 1 {
        signature[64] += 27
    }

    // send transaction to gnosis
    if err := sendGnosisTx(from, to, safe, amount, *safeTxGas, *nonce, encodedTxHash.Hex(), hexutil.Encode(signature)); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    var (
        safe    string = "<SAFE_ADDRESS>"
        from    string = "<SIGNER_ADDRESS>"
        to      string = "<RECEIVER_ADDRESS>"
        privKey string = "<SIGNER_PRIVATE_KEY>"
        amount  int64  = 1000000
    )

    // on rinkeby network
    if err := sendTransaction(from, to, safe, amount, privKey); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err.Error())
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your safe version? in 1.3.0 the chain id is a part of the EIP-712 domain but it looks like in go-ethereum the domain is for older versions

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/signer/core/gnosis_safe.go#L58 vs https://github.com/gnosis/safe-react/blob/dev/src/logic/safe/transactions/offchainSigner/EIP712Signer.ts#L19

Comment: Yes, the safe is in 1.3.0 version

Comment: we created a PR to support newer contract versions https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/24231. Crossing fingers it will be merged